# Product attributes on Woodmart Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After the last update of Woodmart Theme (on 7.0.3) on WooCommerce, a problem was found - I can't change the attributes of the goods:
[Error on product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcsRf.png)
I looked at the page html code - the options are not even loaded.

Has anyone already encountered this? Theme support is silent(((

I tried to change the Wordpress theme - the problem was eliminated.

Comment: For theme issues, it's better to contact the theme authors for support.

Comment: Support is silent for the second day(((